# How To Update Props without re-rendering Parent using React Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been trying to update the **Child** component by passing **different values as props** at different time intervals from the **Parent** component **with no re-rendering of Parent Component**. Child component **doesn't seem to update** on such cases. But when I do setState at Parent component it works, which is for sure **not an ideal approach**. As in case of Angular/Vue it is pretty easy to update the props (or @Input).

Parent Component:

```
function Parent()
{
  let value = 0;

  setTimeout(()=>{value = 10}, 1000);

  return (
    <Child value={value} />
  )
}
```

Child Component:

```
function Child(props)
{
  return (<div>{props.value}</div>)
}
```

Value still prints 0 after 1000ms.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to update the Child component by passing different values as props at different time intervals from the Parent component with no re-rendering of Parent Component.

**In this specific example**, you can't render the child without rendering the parent.

But, it surely can be achieved with higher composition using [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

```
//   v Container with Context provider
<Container>
  <Parent>
//     v Can be rendered without Parent's rendering
    <Child />
  </Parent>
</Container>

//  v In your case, can't be achieved.
<Parent>
//  v Must be aware of props change,
//    therefore, the parent must be rendered.
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

Answer (score -2):

> not an ideal approach

Right. If the parent does not use the state, move it to the Child.

```
 function Parent() {
    return <Child />;
 }

 function Child() {
   const [value, setValue] = useState("");
   useTimeout(() => setValue("Parent doesn't update"), 1000);
   return (<div>{value}</div>)
 }

function useTimeout(fn, time) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
     const timer = setTimeout(fn, time);
     return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
]
```

Comment: Jonas what if the parent is also using the state, and it's parent's responsibility to update the state, hence reflecting the updated state down the hierarchy.

Comment: Thats not what he asked

Comment: @theObserverMan yup, but if the *parent uses the state*, it has to update.